# How to change the background image of a button when clicked in code?

Tags: c#, button, background, windows-phone-8, pressed

There is a similar question like mine here in Stackoverflow but it only explains how to change it in XAML. I want to know how can I change it in code.

Here is a image that shows how I do it in XAML using Blend:

[image]

Link for full size: https://snag.gy/4Skk4.jpg

Basically I want to change the background of a button's pressed state in C# but I can't seem to find any examples on the Internet. It must be in code because sometimes the image of the button will change therefore the button's pressed image must change as well.

The following code is just to change the image of the button and it's just the start.

```
image.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images/Button-warning-icon.png", UriKind.Relative));
image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
buttonWarnings.Background = image;
```

Comment: @Anon I don't have anything, I really don't know how to do it. I have tried to find button methods that allow me to change it but I can't find any.

Comment: Cant you just change the image on the button click event? is that what your wanting?

Comment: Can you confirm what you're trying to change and why it must be in code?

Comment: @sparcopt You don't have anything?? Yes you do. You already have a button. With a background image. And we need to know what kind of button it is, `<input>`, `<asp:ImageButton>` etc. Does it have `runat="server"`? Things like that.

Comment: @MrLister Yes I have that but I don't have anything or any clues about changing the background of a button's pressed state, therefore I don't have any code about that. If you think that posting my button will help I will update the question.

Comment: @MrLister this is Windows Phone, not ASP.NET

Comment: @sparcopt do you want to change it while it's pressed or after it's been pressed? Why can't you do this in XAML, at design time, if you're including the image in the XAP and hardcoding the reference to it?

Comment: @MrLister Exactly, where did I say it as ASP.NET question? One of the tags of the question clearly says "windows-phone-8".

Comment: @MattLacey I want to change it before it's pressed. If there is no way to change it in code perhaps binding it to the button image will work?

Comment: I don't have my code to hand currently (I'll try to dig some out) but I use on mouseleftbuttondown event (silverlight) of the button to change it to the new image, then mouseleftbuttonup to change it back again.

Comment: Also, to add to this, there is a caveat because of the polling frequency (in silverlight - which is close to wp8 stuff) of the mouse, you can left click and move the mouse fast enough and the mouseleftbuttonup event doesn't get called.  So you need also to use mouseleave event to reset the image.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to change the appearance of the Button control in a "pressed" visual state.

I'm not near my dev computer to try it out, but to "unblock you" I'll give a direction.

First, as you noticed in your Blend screenshot, each visual state is represented with a `Storyboard`, which defines how various properties change. In your case, you're looking to change Background property.

The `VisualStateGroups` and their states are defined by the control. You can override them when you re-template the control. So, retemplate the button control using Blend with "Edit Template"->"Edit Copy".

Then, in code, you should be able to do the following:

1) Get visual states (this would not work unless you re-template the control, AFAIK)

```
var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(buttonWarnings);
```

2) Get the VisualStateGroup of "CommonStates" from the visualStateGroups
   collection

```
var commonStatesGroup = visualStateGroups.Find((g) => ((VisualStateGroup)g).Name == "CommonStates") as VisualStateGroup;
```

3) Get the "Pressed" VisualState:

```
var pressedVisualState = commonStatesGroup.Find((vs) => ((VisualState)vs).Name == "Pressed") as VisualState;
```

4) Change the storyboard of that state

```
pressedVisualState.Storyboard = newStoryboardWithCustomImageBackgroundProperty;
```

(**Disclaimer**: I'm not near in a computer to try it now - it's all in theory)

Comment: Yes you understood everything right :) Your solution looks promissing but there is no `find` method :/

Comment: It's a collection - just convert it to whatever collection that supports Find (I think List<T> does).

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples to be found on the internet!
Take a look at some:

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-buttonimage
http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2011/01/windows-phone-image-button/

Answer (score 0):

Actually its quite simple,

While in button pressed state....see part 3 in the image you uploaded above.
Above all the colors there is a row containing 5 icons.

Click on 4th icon.
it will show you option to choose image as background.
[image]